# With Android, how do I pass control back to the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, opencv

I am using the OpenCV Tutorial 3 code (Camera Control) (see [OpenCV4Android samples](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-samples.html)) as the basis for my code and need to be able to open and manipulate an image once it has been saved in the `onPictureTaken()` method. During the manipulation I want to be able to display the changes to the image and post messages using `Toast`, both of which require me to be in the main thread.

Based on advice received to date, I am trying to use a `BroadcastReceiver` in the `Activity` which is triggered by a `sendBroadcast()` in the `JavaCameraView`.

I have updated the `Activity` to include the `BroadcastReceiver`, and register and unregister it as follows:

```
public class Tutorial3Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2, OnTouchListener {
    :
    private ActivityReceiver activityReceiver;
    :
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        :
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        this.registerReceiver(activityReceiver, intentFilter);
        :
    }
    :
    public void onDestroy() {
        :
        this.unregisterReceiver(activityReceiver);
        :
    }
    :
    private class ActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver triggered");
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Tutorial3View.IMAGE_READY)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver received");
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The `sendBroadcast()` is invoked in the `JavaCameraView` as follows:

```
public class Tutorial3View extends JavaCameraView {
    :
    public static final String IMAGE_READY = "IMAGE_READY";
    private Context context;
    :
    public Tutorial3View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        :
        this.context = context;
        :
    }
    :
    public void takePicture(final String fileName) {
        PictureCallback callback = new PictureCallback() {
            private String mPictureFileName = fileName;
            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                :
                image_read();
                :
            }
        };
        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, callback);
    }
    :
    public void image_read() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver - send");
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(IMAGE_READY);
        context.sendBroadcast(i);
        Log.i(TAG, "BroadcastReceiver - sent");
    }
}
```

The `Manifest` includes the `BroadcastReceiver` as follows:

```
<receiver android:name="ActivityReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:label="IMAGE_READY"></intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

When I take the picture, the LogCat shows:

```
03-30 17:22:53.410: I/Sample::Tutorial3View(3174): BroadcastReceiver - send
03-30 17:22:53.410: I/Sample::Tutorial3View(3174): BroadcastReceiver - sent
```

but there is no log for `BroadcastReceiver triggered` or `BroadcastReceiver received`.

Can someone advise why the broadcast isn't being received?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the [`runOnUiThread()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // stuff to be done on UI Thread
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do this.

Use **`doInBackground()`** to do the background image processing operations and when you finish, display the Toast messages inside **`onPostExecute()`**.

Comment: Thanks. However the file is saved outside the main UI thread, so I need to inform the main thread the image is available. How do I do that?

Comment: If you are saving the file in doInBackground(), then you can access the image in onPostExecute(), as it is called only after the background thread has finished working.

Comment: I'm really new to Android development, so I'm not sure how all this is hanging together, but it doesn't look as though doInBackground() is being used. An image is captured from the camera using an onTouch event (in `public class Tutorial3Activity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2, OnTouchListener {..}`) and there's a callback where the image is saved to disk (in `public class Tutorial3View extends JavaCameraView {..}`). I think I need to trigger a method in Tutorial3Activity to open the file and analyse it.

Comment: Oh, so you are using a different class to handle the callback. doInBackground and onPostExecute() are a part of the same class and hence you cant use them. What you can do instead is fire a BroadcastMeassage from Tutorial3View and have a BroadcastReceiver to fire an Intent to Tutorial3Activity, telling it that the file is ready for access. I hope I made sense.

Comment: I'm nearly there, but how do I get an appropriate Context for sendBroadcast() in Tutorial3View?

Comment: I lied! I'm able to pass the Tutorial3Activity context into Tutorial3View and use that for sendBroadcast() but my BroadcastReceiver doesn't appear to be being triggered. I created the BroadcastReceiver within Tutorial3Activity, registered it in onCreate and unregistered it in onDestroy,  but I get no activity from it.

Comment: So, you are saying that your BroadcastReceiver is not being fired ?

Comment: Looks like your activity is not being able to receive the broadcast. Have you declared it as receiver in your Manifest ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html

Comment: I've added the Manifest details for you.

Comment: Everything looks fine to me. I am out of ideas now. :(

Comment: Well thanks for all your help. Just hope someone else can fill in the final pieces of the jigsaw!

Comment: Sorry for letting you down mate. I will try to have a more detailed look at the issue tomorrow, if I get time.

Comment: Appreciate you sticking with me for 6 hours!